# The Href Link in my Mapbox custom control legend doesn't view as a href link. Why is it not clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox

Any help much appreciated.  I have added a custom mapbox control called fs_legend_control in the top-left corner of my map.  Everything works perfectly EXCEPT the link here: `Source: <a href="https://www.example.com/">Read this concerning piste difficulty</a>`

This is the mapbox class:

```
   class fs_legend_control {
        
        onAdd(map) {
        var fs_legend_control_html = ' \
        <div class="my-legend"> \
            <div class="legend-title">Piste Difficulty Legend</div> \
                <div class="legend-scale"> \
                    <ul class="legend-labels"> \
                        <li><span style="background:#339933;"></span>Novice</li> \
                    </ul> \
                </div> \
            <div class="legend-source">Source: <a href="https://www.example.com/">Read this concerning piste difficulty</a></div> \
        </div> \
        ';
            
            this._map = map;
            this._container = document.createElement('div');
            this._container.className = 'fs-legend-control';
            this._container.innerHTML = fs_legend_control_html;
            return this._container;
        }   
        onRemove() {
            this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);
            this._map = undefined;
        }
    }

    map.addControl(new fs_legend_control(), "top-left");
```

I cannot see anything wrong with the CSS either.  Here it is:

```
    .fs-legend-control {
        background: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .my-legend .legend-title {
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 90%;
    }
    .my-legend .legend-scale ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 80%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 15px;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .my-legend .legend-source {
        font-size: 70%;
        color: #999;
        clear: both;
    }
    .my-legend a {
        color: #777;
    }
```

The legend html was taken from [here](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/advanced-legends/).  Any idea why the link is not working and why it is not clickable?  I tried increasing the font size, added z-index: 1000, but no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue a while a go. Mapbox wraps your custom control inside another div, i.e. `mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left`; this class has the following roleset which disables pointer events:

```css
pointer-events: none;
```

try resetting it to `unset` to rewrite this.

P.S. this is a work around and doesn't seem the proper way of handling it. There must be a better approach.

Comment: Many thanks for that ali varste pour.  Never would have thought that.  I am not good at CSS at all.  I tried to add "pointer-events: unset !important; " to all the legend CSS but to no avail.  How would I go about unsetting that please?

Comment: Got it to work with adding pointer-events: auto